# How to allow user to group records on a table?

Tags: usability

I am writing a web based ERP for bus companies. There is a section on the system where the user should be able to divide a route into segments that can (or not) be owned by different bus companies.

Right now it looks like this:
[image]

On the Company column, there is a combobox with the possible companies, and basically the user selects the **company** for each stop, but as you can see, they repeat (and there are routes with ~40 stops that have one company for the first 20 and another for the rest).

One thing I am currently doing is that, lets say the user enters "Tornado" on the 1st stop and **Expreso** on the 20th stop, if this happens, I am auto-selecting Tornado for the 2nd to the 19th stop. But I think is not super clear for the user.

Can you suggest a way to make this easier for the users?

Thanks!

Comment: so one route can be split between different companies? I don't see the columns for stop selection. Have you started working that out? I see a 'location' but is there a numerical order for the stops as well? Assuming there is. Also, it seems bus company is more important than bus type?

Comment: @MikeM, I would assume that the route (order and names of stops) is set elsewhere and cannot be edited here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you though about adding a 'batch edit' system above the table?

Something where you can choose a route section and then define the parameters for the entire section. Maybe something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcnTb4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This should allow for multiple sections to be rapidly defined and edited. If the stops are unevenly placed or the wait times different for a defined section then those controls could be disabled or you could just leave them  off altogether depending on how your system works. You could also add in the vehicle type if necessary.